# different kind of regex to match a url

Tags: php, regex

each part of this regex works alone but when i string them together it does not match a url with http or www followed by one of the listed TLDs.

`(preg_match('/http\:\/\/(www\.)?[a-z](\.com|\.org|\.net|\.mil|\.edu|\.COM|\.ORG|\.NET|\.MIL|\.EDU)$/', $bandUrl))`

Comment: What about `HtTp://wWw.AlSoVaLiD.CoM/`? or `https://secure.com` or `http://some-domain-with-dashes.com` or `http://another.tld` with a tld such as `.mobi`, `.xxx`, `.tv`, not to mention tlds like `.co.uk`

Comment: your list of TDL is missing multi-part TDL E.G .co.uk

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably left out the `+` after `[a-z]` (which btw is not correct to match all valid URLs). And instead of listing both uppercase and lowercase .TLDs, you could use the `/i` flag:

```
preg_match('/http\:\/\/(www\.)?[a-z]+(\.com|\.org|\.net|\.mil|\.edu$/i',
```

Btw, as alternative you could use [`filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL)`](http://php.net/filter_var) for testing.

Comment: thank you so much for your response, this will help me on my journey

Comment: No worries. Should you run into another regex issue, maybe some of the nice analyzation tools here can help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/89718/is-there-anything-like-regexbuddy-in-the-open-source-world

Answer (score 1):

Your `[a-z]` will match only one character (ie www.a.com). You'd be better off making it something like `[a-z0-9\-]+`. Note the `+` means more than one.

Comment: `+` means 'one or more' not 'more than one'

Answer (score 1):

Don't use a regex.

```
filter_var('http://www.example.com', FILTER_VALIDATE_URL);
```

Answer (score 0):

For matching URL following code should work:

```
<?php
    $regex = "((https?|ftp)\:\/\/)?"; // SCHEME
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+(\:[a-z0-9+!*(),;?&=\$_.-]+)?@)?"; // User and Pass
    $regex .= "([a-z0-9-.]*)\.([a-z]{2,3})"; // Host or IP
    $regex .= "(\:[0-9]{2,5})?"; // Port
    $regex .= "(\/([a-z0-9+\$_-]\.?)+)*\/?"; // Path
    $regex .= "(\?[a-z+&\$_.-][a-z0-9;:@&%=+\/\$_.-]*)?"; // GET Query
    $regex .= "(#[a-z_.-][a-z0-9+\$_.-]*)?"; // Anchor
?>

Then, the correct way to check against the regex ist as follows:

<?php
       if(preg_match("/^$regex$/", $url))
       {
               return true;
       }
?>
```

`Courtesy:` Comments made by *splattermania* on PHP manual: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php

Comment: what does the period do before the =  sign--------->>   $regex .=

Comment: period or dot is used in php for concatenation of strings. Here we have a variable $regex that is being used to hold full regular expression by appending various strings.